# MySQL query is not coming back - performance enhancements?

Tags: mysql

I have a shopware database which has the structure:

```
s_articles: all products
id | name | mode

s_order: all orders
id | ordertime | userId | status

s_order_details: all line items for an order
id | orderId | articleId
```

Now I want to achieve the following: I want to now how many users bought a product in the last 90 days which have bought the same product also  earlier than the last 90 days.

I do it like this: I get all articles, then I get count all customers who have bought the article before the last 90 days `"boughtBefore90"`, then I have another sub-select with another sub-select where I collect all the users who have bought the product in the last 90 days  and have bought it earlier than that as well and save it in `"boughtLast90"`.

Then I calcucate the retention rate. This works well with one product, but not with the whole articles database. Is there any way to write this sql with better performance in mind?

My query looks like this:

```
select articleId, articleName, boughtBefore90, boughtLast90, boughtLast90/boughtBefore90 as 'retention'
FROM 

(select
    s_articles.id as 'articleId',
    s_articles.name as 'articleName',
    (select count(*)
        FROM s_order_details as s_order_details_2
        join s_order as s_order_2 on s_order_2.Id = s_order_details_2.orderId
        where s_order_details_2.articleId = s_articles.id
        and (s_order_2.status = 0 or s_order_2.status = 2)
        and s_order_2.ordertime > '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
        and s_order_2.ordertime <  '2017-03-09 23:59:59'
    ) as 'boughtBefore90',
    (select count(*) from s_order_details as s_order_details_3
        join s_order as s_order_3 on s_order_3.id = s_order_details_3.orderId 
        where s_order_3.ordertime > '2017-03-10 00:00:00'
        and s_order_3.ordertime < '2017-06-07 23:59:59'
        and s_order_details_3.articleId = s_articles.id
        and (s_order_3.status = 0 or s_order_3.status = 2)
        AND s_order_3.userId = (
            select DISTINCT(s_order_4.userId) from s_order_details as s_order_details_4
            join s_order as s_order_4 on s_order_4.id = s_order_details_4.orderId 
            where s_order_4.ordertime > '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
            and s_order_4.ordertime < '2017-03-09 23:59:59'
            and s_order_details_4.articleId = s_articles.id
            and s_order_3.userId = s_order_4.userId
            and (s_order_4.status = 0 or s_order_4.status = 2))
    ) as 'boughtLast90'
    from
    s_articles
    join s_order_details on s_order_details.articleID = s_articles.id
    join s_order on s_order.id = s_order_details.orderId
    WHERE s_articles.mode = 0
    AND s_order_details.modus = 0
    AND (s_order.status = 2 or s_order.status = 0)
    group by s_articles.id) as resulttable;
```

Thank you!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a pretty simple query.  Here is the list of customers and articles:

```
select o.customerid, od.articleid
from s_orders o join
     s_order_details od
     on od.orderid = o.id
group by o.customerid, od.articleid
having max(o.ordertime) > curdate() - interval 90 days and
       min(o.ordertime) <= curdate() - interval 90 days;
```

If you want a count, use this as a subquery and use either `count(*)` (for customer/article pairs) or `count(distinct customerid)` (for the number of customers).

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. So this query provides me with the end result of the question how many customers have bought the article in the last 90 days and before that. But now I need the figure of how many have bought it before the 90 days and divide it through your result. I can not go with two subselects here because then the s_articles.id is unknown in the sub select. How can I do this?

Comment: " I want to now how many users bought a product in the last 90 days which have bought the same product also earlier than the last 90 days."